# Passing multiple (or augmented) django querysets to the JQuery DataTables plugin

Tags: jquery, django, datatables, django-queryset

I have a similar issue to a previous poster:

[Is there a way to augment django QuerySets with extra attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999989/is-there-a-way-to-augment-django-querysets-with-extra-attributes)

whereby I need to pass a augmented queryset

i.e.

```
myquerySet = modelOne.objects.all()
for item in myquerySet:
    item.newfield='testtext'   #testtext is not part of the original modelOne
```

to a function (in this case the get_datatables_records function in the jquery DataTables django library). Going into the function the newfield is fine, but (and as pointed out in the previous post) is lost when the passed queryset is reversed (or in this case ordered_by in the function itself). I don't have the option of passing the original queryset first and then attaching the newfield post-function, so am wondering if anyone has any ideas on the best route to take here? For those with further knowledge of the dataTables plugin, should I be doing a secondary callback within the JavaScript functions.

I hope that made sense, and would welcome any advice.

Comment: I meant #newfield is not part of the original modelOne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `extra` query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: Hi Akonsu, I'm not sure using the extra method will work in this case as (from my understanding) it would mean that the .reverse and .order_by would have to be done on myqueryset.extra. These functions are carried out inside the datatables library function where I pass my queryset to, and I don't want to edit this file. Also, and again maybe I'm wrong here, but can't extra only be used on related models. In my case there are no foreignkey/manytomany links involved.

Comment: just pass queryset.extra() to your function. extra() returns a modified query set. also, I do not think extra() is limited to related models only.