# How can i add extra data in object list in django python

Tags: python, django

I am extending the list view and in every object i need to add a dictionary.

My dic look like this

```
mydict1['var1'] = {'value':20, 'result':None}
mydict1['var2'] = {'value':20, 'result':None}
mydict1['var3'] = {'value':20, 'result':None}
```

now i want to add that dictionary to all objects like

```
for myobj in self.get_queryset():
     myobj.add(mydict1)
```

so that i access in my template like this

```
{{myobj.dict1.var1.value}}
```

Comment: @Daniel i want to how to add that dictionary object to current object

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Consider [`.extra()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) and this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999989/is-there-a-way-to-augment-django-querysets-with-extra-attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to set an attribute on your objects?

So this should work:

```
for myobj in self.get_queryset():
     myobj.dict1 = mydict1
```

Comment: `AttributeError` occurs when attempting to retrieve `myobj.dict1`.